# Dual booting Ubuntu and Kali vs Ubuntu and Windows

Tags: dual-boot, windows, kali

Good day everyone,

I recently made the switch from windows 10 to Ubuntu 18.04 after weeks of research regarding dual booting Windows and Linux(Ubuntu & Kali).

I've concluded that the very concept of dual booting Windows and Linux is just too much of a hassle for me, while I know its "do-able" I just think it isn't worth my time and the risk.

But how about dual booting Ubuntu and Kali? In almost every video or document I've found regarding dual booting Ubuntu and Windows, there's always an "Okay" or "Go ahead" on dual booting two Linux distributions, so I ask you this.

1. Why is it okay for two Linux distros and not Windows and Linux? (I am aware that windows updates can ruin the grub boot loader, and while fixing it is "do-able" one can easily mess it up or so I've heard).
2. On the long term can each distribution ruin each other like what Windows does to Linux?
3. Why is it recommended so much or at the very least isn't as shunned as dual booting Linux and Windows

P.S. I'm new to the whole dual booting thing, I am only aware of the pros and cons and not much else that is too technical. But I do have a few years of programming under my belt and I do know how to use google lol, so don't be afraid to be a bit technical hehehhehe

Thank you for your time

Comment: probably because Windows want to be the main and lonely OS on the computer, so it didn't respect other(s) partition(s) and can hurt the GRUB, where Linux OS know their place and respect theirs neighbours (and they can edit the GRUB without messing it because it's not made by Microsoft)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When dual booting two Linux distributions one Linux distribution usually does not effect the other one. In a dual boot only one of the two operating systems can run at the same time, so neither Linux distribution in a dual boot has any effect on the performance of the other one. However Windows updates have been known to overwrite the grub bootloader and the information in the MBR that identifies how and where an operating system is located causing the Linux distribution to be unable to boot.

Linux distros play fair with other Linux distros in a dual boot compared to Windows in a Windows/Linux dual boot system. When Windows does not play fair with the other Linux operating system in a Windows/Linux dual boot, it is sometimes not hard to fix it with Boot-Repair and other tools, and sometimes it requires a lot of skill to get both Windows and Linux to boot properly.

Comment: Also true.  Windows updates have been known to wipe the MBR/whatever they call the GPT table

Comment: @karel RobotHumans said that having more than one distro, kernel upgrades may break my grub config, if so how hard is it to fix? is it too risky like fixing the damage windows would do to a linux partition(by that I mean it wouldn't boot)? because I heard that fixing that damage if not careful may seriously eff up my system

Comment: Linux distros play fair with other Linux distros in a dual boot compared to Windows in a Windows/Linux dual boot system. When Windows does not play fair with the other Linux operating system in a Windows/Linux dual boot, it is sometimes not hard to fix it with Boot-Repair and other tools, and sometimes it requires a lot of skill to get both Windows and Linux to boot properly.

Answer (score 0):

Multibooting a ton of distros is sometimes more cumbersome than Windows/Linux dual booting, because they both expect a /boot partition.  Unless you make more than one, sometimes kernel upgrades will break your grub config.  That said, I have set up multiple boot Linux boxes for linux+linux and linux+windows.  I think I even have a freeBSD+Ubuntu+windows triple boot box laying around somewhere.

Comment: Wow, more than three distros? when your kernel upgraded did it break your grub config? if so, how did you go about fixing it? is it as risky as the effects windows would do to booting linux? cause you see that is the number one thing that turned me off to dual booting... the risk it could do to my system plus I'm not a very careful guy so... hehehe

Comment: The problem with multibooting windows, is it from time to time tries to take over the bootloader without asking.  With multiple linux distros, you have to keep your grub folders in sync, so the two linuces may fight over who gets priority/default/controls the actual installation of grub/mbr.  With freeBSD, you just make a custom grub search file that chainloads the BSD partition and ignores the MBR altogether.